# Opening image in new tab with hyperlink

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I want to open an image in a new tab using a hyperlink. This image came from a database. I have tried this code

```
<td><img src='upload/<?=$row['misper_rep_pic']?>' height='50' width='50'></td>
```

but the image doesn't show when I use a hyperlink. So how can I use a hyperlink here so that I see the image too.

Comment: View the page source and check if the image URL is correct.

Comment: Yes, you can. Anchor element itself won't break your image. You must have done something wrong. Show us how you approached adding this hyperlink.

Comment: You can surround an `img` tag with an `a` tag, that's perfectly valid HTML.  Show us the code you tried and the resulting HTML.  Without seeing the problem, the only answer would be to just use an `a` tag, which you claim didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You question is a bit confusing.

Do you mean like this?

```
<td>
    <a href='upload/<?=$row['misper_rep_pic']?>' target='_blank'>
        <img src='upload/<?=$row['misper_rep_pic']?>' height='50' width='50'>
    </a>
</td>
```